# Regex in SV or UVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What functions do I need to call to use Regular Expressions in Systemverilog/UVM?

Note: I'm not asking how to use regular expressions, just method names.

Comment: This isn't the type of question you ask on StackOverflow, as this is way to broad. This site is for questions to concrete problems, not for tutorials.

Comment: @Tudor Yes I know it's too broad. But I know about regex and all, I just want any of the packages or include files and method names for that purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if you want to use regular expression, you'll need to make sure you're using a UVM library compiled together with its DPI code (i.e. the `UVM_NO_DPI` define isn't set).

The methods you want to use are located in `dpi/uvm_regex.svh`. The main function is `uvm_re_match(...)`, which takes as an argument a regular expression and the string to match against. This is basically a wrapper around the `regexec(...)` C function found in the `regex.h` library. It will return `0` on a match.

Another function you might want to use is `uvm_glob_to_re(...)` which can convert from a glob expression (the kind you get in a Linux shell) to a true regular expression.