# using regex in searching for a field using get_field_by_name

Tags: regex, system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to get a uvm register field by name in systemverilog. I want to use regex, so that I can use a pattern for the field name. Here is my register fields:

```
YY_XXX_2_N
ZZ_BBB_3_N
UU_AAA_8_N
MM_CCC_4_N
YY_WWW_9_N
```

as you can see all register fields are ending with _N, I used the following code to get register field:

```
field=env.my_regmap.get_field_by_name("_N$");
```

so I want this code to get A register field matching the provided pattern. with the code above, I am getting the following error:

```
reporter [RegModel] Unable to locate field '_N$' in block 'my_regmap'
```

I wonder if there is a way to use regex in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_field_by_name()` needs an exact match to return a single handle to a field. What you need to do is use `get_fields()` to build the list of fields, and then use the SV find()

```
uvm_field_reg all_fields[$], selected_fields[$];

all_fields = get_fields();
selected_fields = all_fields.find(item) with (uvm_re_match("*_N",item.get_name));
```

Comment: Thank you!! it works but you have to invert whatever  uvm_re_match function returns     `selected_fields = all_fields.find(item) with (!uvm_re_match(".*_N$",item.get_name()));`

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog does not allow to use regex directly, but UVM provides a DPI function `uvm_re_match` that allows you to use regexec function from regex.h library. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697147/regex-in-sv-or-uvm).

You cannot use this function as an argument to `get_field_by_name` but you can get all fields from register by calling `get_fields` and then check each field with `uvm_re_match`.