# Forcing multiple wires in design in SV/UVM

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm, system-verilog-dpi

I'm new to System Verilog and UVM, and I've already seen this thread:

[Regex in SV or UVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697147/regex-in-sv-or-uvm)

I can't find anywhere a proper example on what kind of syntax should I use to force multiple wires in a design, using regular expressions/wildcards.

For example:

Let's say I have a module called my_fifo, which Is instanced in the design multiple times:

```
top.dut.my_fifo_in
top.dut.master.my_fifo_a
top.dut.slave.axi.my_fifo_out
```

And the block my_fifo contains a wire called:

```
wire force_me_to_1 = 1'b0;
```

I want to force that wire in all instances that start with "my_fifo".
Something like (excuse me for the syntax, it's only for clarifying my intentions):

```
force "*my_fifo*.force_me_to_1" = 1'b1;
```

And it'll make that wire to 1 in all above instances.

Comment: There is no way to do from outside of the module in the language.

Comment: I agree. I wondered whether `uvm_hdl_force` might take a wildcard, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. 
What do you mean by outside of the module? Do you mean that it can't be done as part of interface to a DUT?
What about using assign instead of force?
And last - what would you suggest to do instead?

Comment: I think they meant there is no syntax that allows you to want you want.

Comment: Right, the language does not provide a syntax which would allow you to do it. There are back-door ways, as dave_59 suggested in his answer. But they would require a bit of programming in c/c++ or a scripting language provided by the verilog compiler vendor (most likely tcl-like, if any at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do what you want, however there are some tricks which you might be able to explore in your case.

Supposedly that somewhere in a top instance you define a flag, say *force_me*

```
module tb_top;
    bit force_me = 0;
    ...
endmodule
```

in your module  you can write something like the flowing:

```
module my_fifo;

    logic force_me_to_1;

    always @(tb_top.force_me) begin
        if (tb_top.force_me)
            force force_me_to_1 = 1;
        else
            release force_me_to_1;
    end
    ..
 endmodule
```

now in your testbench you should be able to say

```
 tb_top.force_me = 1;
 ...
 tb_top.force_me = 0;
```

This should force the signal in all instances of the module 'my_fifo' (from inside the module :-))

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. 
I will try to make a test case of it, but maybe you can answer faster what will happen if the bit "tb_top.force_me" will not be defined?

Comment: @EEliaz it you do not define it, the scheme will not work. you will have undefined variable. I am not sure, but verilog might try to define a  one-bit variable for you automatically in this case, see `default_nettype directive. But this would be a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to approach what you want to do: use the VPI or use your tool's command line interface.

Both approaches will involve writing an algorithm that iterates over all instances in the entire design and selecting the names that match your regular expression. Once you have a selected instance, you can apply the individual force command either with a VPI call in C, or a tool command (usually Tcl). Explaining how to do that is too broad a topic to cover in this forum.

Both approaches require that you turn of certain tool optimizations that preserve the signal names you want to force. That could be a severe performance penalty. So you should investigate alternatives to your approach.